# SQL Statement - Select data from database with condition - MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have written a sql statement to select the data from my database in mvc4 .

what i try to is to select all data which i compare with a value.

here is what mean:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("DefaultConnection");
    var data = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Mag WHERE mytitle= model=>model.title");
}
```

i want to make a condition to filter the data.

and then in html do this:

```
 <ol>
        @foreach (var image in data)
        { 
           <li>
               <img src="@Url.Content(image.picpath)"/>
           </li>
        }
    </ol>
```

anyone knows how it works?. i have search a lot but can´t anything.

any help are appreciated:

Comment: Suggestions: the question doesn't really have much to do with asp.net or MVC. Please specify what data access technology you're using (that Database.Open call could be anything really). Don't do these kinds of things in the view - controllers are there for that purpose (if you don't want to abstract it even further in services). Either way, you will want to use whatever facilities your data access framework provides for these kinds of things - parameters most likely. If data access technology is Entity Framework or similar you're going about it the wrong way entirely.

Comment: If you're using MVC4, you should be using Entity Framework. At the very least, you should be using *some kind of ORM*. Unless, you're making very specific, highly-optimized database queries, there is *zero* reason to manually submit a database query anymore. Entity Framework is open-source, peer-reviewed, and mature. Again, unless it's an *extremely* unique scenario, the query EF generates will always be more efficient than what you come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, move that code out of the view and put it in the Controller. You should avoid putting Data Access code in a View because you are breaking the MVC pattern.

Second, if you move that code to an Action in your Controller, you can do this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var myModel = GetMyModel();//However you do it
    var db = Database.Open("DefaultConnection");
    //DON'T USE THE ACTUAL QUERY BELOW. IT EXPOSES YOU TO SQL INJECTION
    //USE PARAMETERS INSTEAD. I'm sure your db OBJECT allows you to use them. 
    var data = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Mag WHERE mytitle= model='{0}'",myModerl.Title);

    return View("YourView", data);
}
```

Now your view, can be strongly typed:

```
@model IEnumerable<YourModel> 

<ol>
     @foreach (var image in Model)
     { 
        <li>
             <img src="@Url.Content(image.picpath)"/>
        </li>
     }
</ol>
```

Finally, as I mentioned in the code comment, don't use string concatenation to build your SQL statements. I am sure that whatever you use to access your data, allows you to specify parameters instead.

Also, never do `select * from ...`. Select only the columns you need and no more. If a column gets added to that table in the future (for example a humongous BLOB) you will be retrieving that column also unnecessarily.